# Implement a web tier and a data tier on Azure

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

So, I made 3 VMs in a cloud service. All of them have apache, php, mysql, phpmyadmin installed on them. 
2 VMs are in the same availability set "WebTierAS" and the last VM is in the availability set "DataTierAS".
The first two VMs have my site files and in the last VM, I made a database. How do I make sure when I open ip-address/phpmyadmin, it takes me to the 3rd VM?

Or if anyone can provide links to the demonstration of implementing any such thing, that would be really helpful too!

Comment: This question belongs on ServerFault. Having said that: This question is actually answered in several other questions (such as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27937432/272109) talking about directly accessing instances of a database).

Comment: This question is answered in fairly good detail on Server Fault: http://serverfault.com/questions/580544/azure-two-vms-in-cloud-service-can-not-rdp-to-one